When opening a Webstorm project, the project window opens then closes immediately
After rebooting my Mac, Webstorm only opened one of the three projects I had open before rebooting.  When I try to open either of the other two projects, the project window appears briefly and then disappears. I have tried this multiple times, all with the same result.
I looked in the file ~/Library/Logs/JetBrains/WebStorm2024.1/idea.log and found the Exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attributeRecord[id:1026394][#0]{attributeId: 14, dedicatedId: 1108509} dedicatedId must be != 0
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.lambda$checkAttributeRecordSanity$0(AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.java:226)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.dev.blobstorage.StreamlinedBlobStorageOverMMappedFile.readRecord(StreamlinedBlobStorageOverMMappedFile.java:220)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.dev.blobstorage.StreamlinedBlobStorageHelper.readRecord(StreamlinedBlobStorageHelper.java:217)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.checkAttributeRecordSanity(AttributesStorageOverBlobStorage.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.VFSHealthChecker$verifyFileRecords$2$checkSingleFileTask$1.invoke(VFSHealthChecker.kt:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.VFSHealthChecker$verifyFileRecords$2$checkSingleFileTask$1.invoke(VFSHealthChecker.kt:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.insideReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.access$insideReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:16)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$tryReadCancellable$2.invoke(InternalReadAction.kt:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$tryReadCancellable$2.invoke(InternalReadAction.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt$cancellableReadActionInternal$1.invoke$lambda$1$lambda$0(cancellableReadAction.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.tryRunReadAction(RwLockHolder.kt:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:958)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt$cancellableReadActionInternal$1.invoke$lambda$1(cancellableReadAction.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtilService.runActionAndCancelBeforeWrite(ProgressIndicatorUtilService.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runActionAndCancelBeforeWrite(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt$cancellableReadActionInternal$1.invoke(cancellableReadAction.kt:34)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CoroutinesKt.blockingContextInner(coroutines.kt:320)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CoroutinesKt.blockingContext(coroutines.kt:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt.cancellableReadActionInternal(cancellableReadAction.kt:31)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.tryReadCancellable(InternalReadAction.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.tryReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.readLoop(InternalReadAction.kt:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.access$readLoop(InternalReadAction.kt:16)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$runReadAction$4.invokeSuspend(InternalReadAction.kt:44)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)


I clicked File -> Invalidate Caches and checked "Clear file system cache and Local History" and then clicked the "Invalidate and Restart" button. When Webstorm restarted, the projects that were closing immediately now remain open.
